# Plugin with single item ( october cms )

Tags: laravel, octobercms

Trying to create single page in builder plugin to have some custom configurable fields, but within builder specifics there should be list and item, how can i achieve that, or i missed something?

Or maybe I can achieve this without using builder?

There is another way, but I think it is not right: create single item and redirect to it's item update page.

Please provide me best way to do this.
Thanks in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want create single page with custom configurable fields you should use [Rainlab Static Pages plugin](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-pages) with [Snippets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxOdQ.png).